# using MERGE in 9i

Tags: oracle, merge, oracle9i

I want to do something like this in 9i

```
MERGE INTO SAT_DEMANDS D
      USING (SELECT DISTINCT d1.PRODUCT_ID AS product_id, CA.CUST_ID as allocated_cust  
        FROM CDP_MPS_ALLOCATION CA, sat_demands d1
        WHERE substr(d1.product_id,1,instr(d1.product_id,'_VIRTUAL',1)-1) = ca.prod_id(+)) MC
        ON (D.PRODUCT_ID = MC.product_id AND D.CUSTOMER_ID = MC.allocated_cust)
        WHEN matched then 
        Update set D.alloc_cust_id_s = CASE WHEN mc.allocated_cust IS NULL THEN 'FREE'
                                       ELSE mc.allocated_cust||':'||'FREE'
                                       END;
```

Please help!
Oracle 9i does not allow me to do this since it does not have when not matched. how do I achieve the same result in 9i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a rowid approach:

```
FOR r in (SELECT D.rowid, MC.allocated_cust FROM
           (SELECT DISTINCT d1.PRODUCT_ID AS product_id, CA.CUST_ID as allocated_cust  
               FROM CDP_MPS_ALLOCATION CA, sat_demands d1
             WHERE substr(d1.product_id,1,instr(d1.product_id,'_VIRTUAL',1)-1) = ca.prod_id(+)
            ) MC
            join SAT_DEMANDS D
            ON (D.PRODUCT_ID = MC.product_id AND D.CUSTOMER_ID = MC.allocated_cust)
         )
LOOP

        Update SAT_DEMANDS D
        set D.alloc_cust_id_s = CASE WHEN r.allocated_cust IS NULL THEN 'FREE'
                                     ELSE r.allocated_cust||':'||'FREE'
                                       END
        where rowid=r.rowid;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Hi Florin, this was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 9i **does** have the [WHEN NOT MATCHED](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/statements_915a.htm#2080942) clause. You can't use update however with it.

In your case you don't need merge, UPDATE should do what you want:

```
UPDATE sat_demands d
   SET alloc_cust_id_s = nvl((SELECT mc.allocated_cust || ':FREE'
                               FROM mc
                              WHERE d.product_id = mc.product_id
                                AND d.customer_id = mc.allocated_cust),
                             'FREE')
```

Comment: his query does not have when not matched, not oracle's merge :)

Comment: @Florin: I think the OP wants to update the table, whether there is a match or not. I may have misinterpreted the question though :)

Comment: sure, he wants to update the table, and a simple update is almost ok, excepting the situation when there is no match for a (product_id, customer_id). In this case he should set alloc_cust_id_s = nvl( newvalue, alloc_cust_id_s). that is, update at the same value.

Comment: And if there is matching for few rows(let's say 1%) the update becomes ineficient. But, in most cases is ok.