# Cursor locking the table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

```
    declare 
     CURSOR C1 
      IS select tgt.exp_date ,(src.eff_date - 1/(24*60*60))eff_date 
         from mira_rate tgt,mira_rate_dummy src
       where src.tc_code = tgt.tc_code and src.carrier_code = tgt.carrier_code and tgt.exp_date is null for update of tgt.exp_date;
       v_a date;
       v_b date;
        i number:=0;
      begin 
      open c1;
      loop
        fetch c1 into v_a, v_b;
        exit when c1%notfound;

        update mira_rate 
        set exp_date =v_b where current of c1;
        i:=i+1;
        end loop;

        dbms_output.put_line(i||' rows updated');

      close c1;
   commit;
      end;
```

After i excecute the query it is locking the table says

ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified

Also pls tell me how to remove the lock i tried killing the sesssion it is not happening.still it  says the same

Affter removing the lock. Pls clear me this requirement

```
select tgt.exp_date ,(src.eff_date - 1/(24*60*60))eff_date 
             from mira_rate tgt,mira_rate_dummy src
           where src.tc_code = tgt.tc_code and src.carrier_code = tgt.carrier_code and tgt.exp_date is null;
```

it ill return rows I need to goto the mira_rate table need to update exp_date=eff_date.

Please suggest me how to do i m using Oracle 9i so merge without not matched is working

Comment: It is because you have selected 'FOR UPDATE'. Are you sure you need that ?

Comment: How to do that without that?? can u give me the query by removing that

Comment: have you tried the code with commit? (which is now included after your edit.)

Comment: attention, I'll put the commit after the `close c1;`.

Comment: Also tell me how to remove the lock pls..I killed the session it is not happening.

Comment: I doubt the commit is relevant, plus, I would only VERY rarely do transactions in PL/SQL.  The problem is that the cursor is locking the record you are trying to update.  Take out the 'FOR UPDATE'.

Comment: this code does not lock mira_rate. the table is locked by something else.

Comment: @FlorinGhita: Something else. I m running only this query

Comment: oops - yes you are right - my bad. Nevertheless, try taking it out. (I am thinking there is a trigger somewhere ...)

Comment: @HughJones: How to remove the lock first . I killed the session but still it says the same error:(

Comment: You probably have to wait - it depends on whether you have admin rights ...

Comment: @Satheesh you (or your dba if you have no privs) can see the sessions that are holding locks with `select * from dba_dml_locks where name in ('MIRA_RATE', 'MIRA_RATE_DUMMY');`. some other session (not your session that is getting the error) is holding row/table locks on the tables.

Comment: @DazzaL: In case if it is locked there is no other way to remove the lock?

Comment: Somebody help me in removing the lock. i tried it is not hapening

Comment: @Satheesh to remove the lock: Find the session that holds the lock. (I gave you some links as comments on my answer. However you can google: Oracle find locks). Kill that session OR commit or rollback in that session, and the lock will be released.

Comment: Pls help me in creating the query which i Mentioned in the 2nd aprt of the question

Comment: @FlorinGhita: I m using Oracle 9i I cannot give without not matched statement in MERGE

Answer (score 3):

At first sight, there is no commit in the code.

The code with commit wil be ok. Commit will release the locks([Oracle cursor examples/expl](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10472/static.htm#CHDGEHBF))

But better you would:

```
MERGE INTO mira_rate tgt
USING mira_rate_dummy src
ON (src.tc_code = tgt.tc_code and src.carrier_code = tgt.carrier_code)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET exp_date= src.eff_date - 1/(24*60*60) --or just src.eff_date
WHERE tgt.exp_date is null;
```

This is what you want to do as far as I understand.

As a rule: What you can do in SQL, do in SQL, not PL/SQL.

Comment: I tried commit ..still it is locked how to remove the lock..I killed the session still it is locked.

Comment: [http://www.praetoriate.com/oracle_tips_find_locks.htm](http://www.praetoriate.com/oracle_tips_find_locks.htm) , [http://psoug.org/reference/locks.html](http://psoug.org/reference/locks.html)

Comment: I l try but can you tell me how to remove the lock which i already happnd. i tried killing the session but still same

Comment: Yes - be patient - go get a cup of coffee and wait for the lock to release.

Comment: @HughJones: How much does it take? I m waiting for 15 mins

Comment: +1 - the comment about commit is not correct, but a single sql statement is the way forward. (Let Oracle decide what to lock and what not )

Comment: @HughJones:It is not removing the lock .

Comment: I reckon by the time you have modified your stored procedure to implement Florin's suggestion of a single update statement (with no for update cursor) it will have returned to you.

Comment: @HughJones Commit or Rollbak realease the locks. Read here [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10472/static.htm#CHDGEHBF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10472/static.htm#CHDGEHBF)

Comment: Perhaps have a skim read of this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168/why-are-relational-set-based-queries-better-than-cursors

Comment: @Florin - yes but Satheesh needs to simplify.  Perhaps 'Not correct' was too strong, 'Not the way I would do it' is more accurate.

Comment: @HughJones Ok, I have believed that you say that commit won't help to release the lock. His problem is the lock. The better solution is a bonus from me :)

Comment: Now My problem or query is 

select tgt.exp_date ,(src.eff_date - 1/(24*60*60))eff_date 
         from mira_rate tgt,mira_rate_dummy src
       where src.tc_code = tgt.tc_code and src.carrier_code = tgt.carrier_code and tgt.exp_date is null

Select the row it needs to update in mira_rate. I need to update this row exp_date with  eff_date

Comment: I ve given the requirement in the question in 2nd part claeraly.Pls check there

Comment: @FlorinGhita:I m using Oracle 9i Without not matched I am not able to give

Comment: @HughJones:this is returning more than one row SELECT SRC.EFF_DATE - 1/86400 
    FROM MIRA_RATE_DUMMY SRC
    WHERE 
      SRC.TC_CODE = TGT.TC_CODE AND
      SRC.CARRIER_CODE = TGT.CARRIER_CODE

Comment: You can try the responses from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266880/using-merge-in-9i)

Comment: But if you are on 9i, your code is also ok, because you can't use MERGE. As a note your question is tagged Oracle10g

Answer (score 1):

Take out the 'FOR UPDATE'.

You need to be very clear in your mind why you need it and in my experience you generally don't.

Between us I think we are saying this should be your approach

```
begin
  UPDATE mira_rate 
  SET exp_date= src.eff_date - 1/(24*60*60)
  WHERE exp_date is null;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
    (TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT) || ' Rows Updated);

end;
```

No need for locks and no need for cursors.

Hope that helps.

Edit - still not entirely sure what your requirement is but the following sql may be what you are looking for.

```
UPDATE MIRA_RATE TGT
SET EXP_DATE = 
  (
    SELECT SRC.EFF_DATE - 1/86400 
    FROM MIRA_RATE_DUMMY SRC
    WHERE 
      SRC.TC_CODE = TGT.TC_CODE AND
      SRC.CARRIER_CODE = TGT.CARRIER_CODE
  )
WHERE
  TGT.EXP_DATE IS NULL;
```

Comment: Yes i l try but it is already locked.How to remove the lock first . I killed the session but still it says the same error

Comment: +1 for answer and @Satheesh : http://www.erpgreat.com/oracle-database/removing-table-lock.htm

Comment: Yes I removed the lock.But can you tell me how to change the above query according to my requiremnt

Comment: @HughJones :In your answer pls join tables and put

Comment: @HughJones: SELECT SRC.EFF_DATE - 1/86400 
    FROM MIRA_RATE_DUMMY SRC
    WHERE 
      SRC.TC_CODE = TGT.TC_CODE AND
      SRC.CARRIER_CODE = TGT.CARRIER_CODE Is returning more than one row

Comment: Then you need to post some table definitions - without it we cannot determine what unique or primary keys are available.

Comment: @Satheesh - I don't wish to sound unkind, but you need some basic tuition (and experience) in Sql.  You have my sympathy because we all started somewhere.  'Returning More Than Row' means that the second query in brackets finds more than one record for each tc_code, carrier_code.  You could add 'AND ROWNUM = 1' to the inner where clause to get the thing to run, but I cannot advise you on the MEANING of your results.

Comment: I understand sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

@Satheesh, Updatable select will work only for primary key columns. See if the select fetches the primary key and also useins it in where clause. Else the update will throw error.
There is something to check for 
`cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`
You can have join but the update needs primary key to update in the base table.